# Fix one text value in an excel spreadsheet from a text document

Tags: microsoft-excel

Looking for an automated solution.  I work for a nonprofit and I'm trying to clean up a medium sized database.  I've exported to Excel.  Columns are:
Name
Donation
Date

I have a separate txt export that has the name and address of the companies separated by commas, but when I try to create a CSV from this export, I have two columns
Name 
Company Address - with the address on one line, then city/town, state and zip on another

What I need is a spreadsheet that has the following columns:
Name
Donation
Date
Address
City/Town
State
Zip

There are a few thousand entries, so need to automate!

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

If the name is unique you can use `VLOOKUP` and get the data from the second worksheet and write into the first. For example name is in `A2`, Donation in `B2` and Date in `C2` then you can write in `D2` a formula like the following if name is in column A and required data say city is in column D in the second worksheet i.e., "'Sheet2'":

```
VLOOKUP(A2, 'Sheet2'!A2:D1000,4,false)
```

The above formula is expecting that there are 999 rows in 'Sheet2' - 2 to 1000. Change the range as per your data. Wherever the name appears from row 2 to 1000 in 'Sheet2'  data in column D of that row will be read and brought to your sheet. Do the same for other data elements as well.

Answer (score 0):

Can you confirm how you are importing the txt into excel.  Are you copy pasting, or are you using the import data from text function?

If you are importing, you can just choose the "delimited" option and then select the comma as the seperator.  This should then import your data into individual columns.  Once this is done, you should easily be able to reference the data with a lookup function

If this is what you are doing, then I would need to see an example of how the text file is set up to see why it isn't working.